# Xamarin Studio. Save failed: couldn't perform atomic initialization

Tags: macos, xamarin, save, filesystems

I'm at a loss, the disk has around 300GB free and when checking on finder all the files are read/write enabled.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I went to **Xamarin Studio > Preferences > Version Control > Check 'Disable Version Control globally'** and it worked. Seems that it comes from svn feature inside of Xamarin. Hope it works for you.